# load all reviews and all ratings of a specific product using product id

Tags: product, ratings

I want to load all reviews and all ratings of a specific product using product id so i have made a module but problem is that i am not able to load detail reviews and detail rating of any specific product using product id only. i want to use it on categories page. i want this

[image]
and i have completed jquery part only product loading part is left please help me as soon as possible. I want to use foreach command not any other command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <?php 
 $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
 $_product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
 $reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review') ->getResourceCollection() 
 ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()) 
 ->addEntityFilter('product', $productId) 
 ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED) 
 ->setDateOrder() ->addRateVotes();
 $avg = 0; $avgper = 0; $totalrv = 0; $totalrvper =0; $ratings = array();       
 $count = 0;
 $star5 = 0; $star4 = 0; $star3 = 0; $star2 = 0; $star1 = 0;
 echo $review;
 if (count($reviews) > 0) { 
     foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) { 
         $mysum = 0;
         foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) { 
             $mysum = $mysum + ($vote->getPercent());
             $ratings[] = $vote->getPercent();
         } 
         $torat = $mysum/count($review->getRatingVotes());

         if ($torat <= 100 && $torat > 80) {
             $star5 = $star5 + 1;
         }
         if ($torat <= 80 && $torat > 60) {
             $star4 = $star4 + 1;
         }
         if ($torat <= 60 && $torat > 40) {
             $star3 = $star3 + 1;
         }
         if ($torat <= 40 && $torat > 20) {
             $star2 = $star2 + 1;
         }
         if ($torat <= 20 && $torat >= 0) {
             $star1 = $star1 + 1;
         } 
     } 
     $avg = array_sum($ratings)/count($ratings);
     //echo("<br>".$star5."<br>".$star4."<br>".$star3."<br>".$star2."
 <br>".$star1."<br>");
     $totalsum = $star5+$star4+$star3+$star2+$star1;
     //echo($totalsum);
     ?>
<div class="rating_main">
      <div class="rating_left">
      <table border="0" border-collapse="collapse" style="line-height: 13px;">
              <caption style="text-align:center; padding: 5px 0px;"><?php printf("%.2f", $avg*.05) ?> out of 5 
              <i class="fa fa-star fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></caption>
              <tr>
                  <td class="rating-table-margin">5 <i class="fa fa-star fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                  <td><div class="meter"><span style="width: <?php echo ((100/$totalsum)*$star5) ?>%"></span><p></p></div></td>
                  <td class="rating-table-margin"><?php echo $star5 ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="rating-table-margin">4 <i class="fa fa-star fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                  <td><div class="meter"><span style="width: <?php echo ((100/$totalsum)*$star4) ?>%"></span><p></p></div></td>
                  <td class="rating-table-margin"><?php echo $star4 ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="rating-table-margin">3 <i class="fa fa-star fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                  <td><div class="meter"><span style="width: <?php echo ((100/$totalsum)*$star3) ?>%"></span><p></p></div></td>
                  <td class="rating-table-margin"><?php echo $star3 ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="rating-table-margin">2 <i class="fa fa-star fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                  <td><div class="meter"><span style="width: <?php echo ((100/$totalsum)*$star2) ?>%"></span><p></p></div></td>
                  <td class="rating-table-margin"><?php echo $star2 ?></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="rating-table-margin">1 <i class="fa fa-star fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                  <td><div class="meter"><span style="width: <?php echo ((100/$totalsum)*$star1) ?>%; background-color: red;"></span><p></p></div></td>
                  <td class="rating-table-margin"><?php echo $star1 ?></td>
              </tr>              
      </table></div>
      <div>
        <div class="rating_right"><?php printf("%.2f", $avg*.05) ?><i class="fa fa-star fa-2" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 25px; position: relative; top: -3px;"></i>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; padding-left: 4px; width: 47%; ">Total Review(s) : <?php echo($totalsum); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php    
}
 ?>
 And also I used some css and jQuery and get this result
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you use below script to get all reveiew and rating .

```
 <?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);

$productId = $_product->getId();
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
                ->getResourceCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addEntityFilter('product', $productId)
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->setDateOrder()
                ->addRateVotes();

$avg = 0;
$ratings = array();
if (count($reviews) > 0) {
    foreach ($reviews->getItems() as $review) {
        foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {
            Mage::log('2 if');
            Mage::log($vote->getData());
            $ratings[] = $vote->getPercent();
        }
    }

    $avg = array_sum($ratings)/count($ratings);
}
echo 'avg'.$avg;

?>
```

Comment: If above answer will help you, please accept it, So it will help other in community.

Comment: There is a big problem with this coding. Basically % of rating generated by your coding is different from rating seen on product page. I am using magento1924. I magento sample data product "Racer Back Maxi Dress" product detail page rating % is 100, 93.33, 53.33, 80, 93.33. But  accourding to your coding it is 100, 100, 40, 80, 100. I do not know that where is problem.

Comment: you print log of object and check. i used this coode in my axtension and it works fine

Comment: I get all solution

Comment: And solution is below